# Quick question on basic Basic concept of experience replay

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

Due to my admitted newbie's understanding on the field, I'm about to ask a dummy question.

While sampling batches, for example experience replay buffer which contains number of samples, after getting **n** (size of a batch) of loss values through forward propagation, what way will the weights updates follow:

- Update all weights based on all losses **separately**, like iterating through that **n** losses to update
- Update all weights based on **the mean** (or maybe standard deviation) of all losses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd one is the correct one. We update the weights according to the mean squared error between real value (in case of DQN it is a bootstrapped value) and the current value prediction, obtained for every sample ($s,a,R_t$) in the minibatch. In other words your network is going to get "corrected", for every prediction it has made, by the difference between estimation and ground truth values.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but i was just doubting: suppose i set my experience relay buffer to 64, i would have to update every single weight through 64 MSEs(means 64 backpropate) after every single action. Am i getting it right cause it's gonna be a computational explosion in a large scale

Comment: You have to update your weights towards the direction that minimize the MEAN squared error. In other words you want the weights, that with them, the network performs better in the minibatch. It will be 64 SE and you are searching for the weights that with them the network will minimize the mean of the 64 SE. I tried different ways to communicate the minimization of the MSE. If this is not sufficient let me know.